# how to track face in VisionOS environment

Tags: visionos, vision-pro

I'm a person who develops iPad apps in my company. Previously, I used to track my face through ARKit. Soon, I have to track my face with Vision OS, but I saw Apple's official document that ARFaceAnchor of ARKit, which I originally used, is not supported by Vision OS.
By any chance, what method should I use to track my face in visionos?

I'm curious about how to track your face in vision os environment.